# cascade parameter from jsp to servlet using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, jquery-ui

I have a jsp form with different type of fields; selects and radio buttons.

I am trying to send the radio button and select to a servlet via a jQuery script.

It was working fine if I sent the select value. I tried adding radio button as well which is not working.

`var radiotype` is nothing but a radio field in my jsp form.

```html
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#selType').change(function(event) {
      var selType = $("select#selType").val();
      var radiotype = $("#radioid").val();
      $.get('JsonServlet', {
        selTypeList: selType,
        radiotype: radiotype
      }, function(jsonResponse) {
        var select = $('#listtemplate');
        console.log("select" + select);
        select.find('option').remove();
        $.each(jsonResponse, function(index, value) {
          $('<option>').val(value).text(value).appendTo(select);
        });
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would first advise you review the Web Console > Network section to see if there are strange Request or Response headers or details. It's possible that maybe you're not sending the data you're expecting to send. Also the response from the API may not be what you're expecting either.

I do not see any issues with the code you're using. I would advise some minor changes:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('#selType').change(function(event) {
      var selType = $("#selType").val();
      var radiotype = $("#radioid").val();
      console.log("Select", selType, "Radio", radiotype);
      $.getJSON('JsonServlet', {
        selTypeList: selType,
        radiotype: radiotype
      }, function(resp) {
        var sObj = $('#listtemplate');
        sObj.html("");
        console.log("Response", resp);
        $.each(resp, function(k, v) {
          $('<option>').val(v).html(v).appendTo(sObj);
        });
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

As I said, nothing wrong with what you had, yet this introduces a few shortcuts. Using `$.getJSON()` just helps ensure that it is expecting JSON Data to be returned.